# How to achieve the lowest usage of server resources for this PHP/MySQL issue?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a system where users get paid to click advertisements and I need to keep track of the amount of advertisements a user has clicked for the last 7 days. To do this I figured 2 ways:

1. For each advertisement clicked, there will be inserted an entry into the database table 'ads_clicked'. Each day the entries that are older than 7 days will be cleared (cronjob script).
2. For each advertisement clicked, there will be inserted an entry into the database table 'ads_clicked'. However this time each log will only remain in the database table for 1 day. Each end of the day the ads clicked will be calculated for each user and saved in a field 'ck_1' ( in the table 'users' ) which holds the ads clicked yesterday. There'll also be ck_2 (= ads clicked 2 days ago), ck_3, etc., which will be moved each day ( ck_7 = ck_6, ck_6 = ck_5, etc. ).

Both ways are possible but the 2nd way requires UPDATE queries in the cronjob script that's ran daily and the 1st way does not. However using the 2nd way it will be easier to display the ads clicked over the last 7 days for each user as it's just stored inside fields (ck_1, ck_2,etc.) which are part of the user entry in the database, while using the 2nd way I'd need to calculate it ( counting the rows in 'ads_clicked' table for each day ) every time I want to display the ads clicked over the last 7 days.

Do notice that the website may get huge traffic and thus lots of entries made to the 'ads_clicked' table, so I need to be sure which way is most efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I dont know about the resources, but option 2 makes me shiver. Also it's not realtime for the "today" data.. Id definitely say: go for option 1, the second is terrible design :D

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I agree that option 2 seems rather bad, design-wise, however I considered it since I have seen this been done in another paid to click system, which made me doubt which way is better. Thanks for confirming ^^!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real way to know how each option is going to preform with your data on your hardware is to try it both ways and measure the results. (And if you do that, post an update here.)

I created a similar system a while back and went with something like option 1. It's the simplest and most straightforward way to do it. If you eventually determine that MySQL inserts just can't possibly cope with the level of data you're trying to insert, it should be pretty easy to replace this with a cache or a message queue or some other fancy new thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured option 1 would be most straightforward as well, but I wasn't too sure about whether interacting with a table containing (ten/hundreds of) thousands of entries may slow down the website a lot. I guess I'll just go with that way and find out.

Comment: Try it out and see! If your interaction with it is simply inserting records, I think you'll find it preforms very well. Depending on how your indexing is set up, it doesn't really matter how many rows their are. The similar system I designed has tens of millions of rows.

Comment: Wow, well then I guess it'll be doing just fine! Thanks again, I'll go with option 1 as I expect no more than a few thousands of entries to be stored in the table every week and all that has to be done is inserting them and selecting SUM(*) to get the amount of ads a user clicked on a specific day or period.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with option 2 I would suggest you create a separate table for the user clicks, that way you won't lock access to the users table when you're doing heavy processing with the cron job.

Another thing: don't insert clicks right away. You can do this (if it's possible to you) by saving those clicks in a memory cache such as memcached and every ten minutes or so fetch those clicks (maybe even do some processing to minimize inserts) and insert that batch of clicks to the 'ads_clicked' table, only making one load spike instead of several continuous ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest I'm personally not quite familiar with the memory cache thing so I'm not sure how I would do that. Also I'm still a bit worried about the amount of entries that would go into that table 'ads_clicked', whether that would slow down the website, even though I know that one table can contain millions of entries.